# NativeScript Vue RadAutoCompleteTextView programmatically remove all tokens

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

There's a removeAllTokens method [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radautocompletetextview.html#removealltokens) and I've seen how to trigger another method from the [docs](https://github.com/ProgressNS/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/master/autocomplete/app/examples/preselected-tokens/autocomplete-preselected-tokens-model.ts), however it is for angular in the docs and I'm not sure how I can call the removeAllTokens method as I'm using NS-Vue.

An insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an id on your autocomplete element and when you programmatically want to remove all tokens, just use this

```
import { Frame } from '@nativescript/core'

const autoCompleteView = Frame.topmost().getViewById('<id of autocomplete view>');
if (autoCompleteView && typeof autoCompleteView.removeAllTokens === 'function') {
  autoCompleteView.removeAllTokens();
}
```